# Symfony2/Doctrine2 - yaml model extending?

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, yaml

I'm writing an application and currently I'm working on models. I use YAML to define my models. Now there are multiple tables where some fields are repeating (like user_id, comment_counter, created_at, etc.). For example for `created_at` field - there will be always the same code to set the value. Writing it on many models seems not ok in OOP context. Now my question is - can I define a base model in YAML, so I can derive from it or is it possible (?) only when using annotations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP trait or have your models that share common fields extend a PHP base model so that you don't have to redefine the fields, getters, and setters in each entity. This way you reduce some of your duplicate code but you will still have to define the fields such as `created_at` in each of your YAML definitions for each model.